# Configuring Debian's opendkim package's init script parameters with both init.d and systemctl scripts being present

Tags: debian, systemd, sysvinit

In the midst of me configuring postfix and opendkim, I decided to upgrade Debian jessie (oldstable) to stretch. Since then, I can't get opendkim to start up properly.

What I expect is that the configuration in /etc/default/opendkim should be honoured, in particular that the RUNDIR and SOCKET settings should be place within the postfix chroot:

```
# Command-line options specified here will override the contents of
# /etc/opendkim.conf. See opendkim(8) for a complete list of options.
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
# Change to /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim to use a Unix socket with
# postfix in a chroot:
RUNDIR=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
# Uncomment to specify an alternate socket
# Note that setting this will override any Socket value in opendkim.conf
SOCKET=local:$RUNDIR/opendkim.sock
USER=opendkim
GROUP=opendkim
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
EXTRAAFTER=
```

However, regardless of whether I reboot, execute "service opendkim start" or "/etc/init.d/opendkim start", /var/run/opendkim is used as the RUNDIR instead, and so the pid file and socket are placed in the wrong locations:

```
/usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

I've read that this is because the /etc/init.d/opendkim file (as with all other debian init files) includes the LSB init functions at /lib/lsb/init-functions, which runs the systemd script at /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd, which in turn redirects execution to be "systemctl start opendkim"

This means that the unit file in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/opendkim.service is read, and the ExecStart line within it is executed

I've also read that I can skip the systemctl redirect by setting the env variable _SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT before the lsb init functions are included.

What is the correct way for me to configure opendkim now?

a. Should I still edit /etc/default/opendkim and add the _SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT to /etc/init.d/opendkim?

b. How is the systemctl unit file in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/opendkim.service generated, and is it supposed to be smart enough to include my configuration?  i.e. am I don't something wrong?

c. Or should I edit the ExecStart line directly?

Comment: It's probably safer to backup the configuration files, then `apt-get purge opendkim`, `apt-get install openkdim` and then manually edit the new installed configuration files, if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the above.

- Do not muck about with `_SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT`.  That's an internal mechanism that is none of your business.
- The unit file is not in that location.  That is a symbolic link.  The systemd unit file is `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service`.
- Do not edit the systemd unit file.  It is supplied by the OpenDKIM package for Debian and is not supposed to be modified.
- It is a good rule of thumb in general that an answer misplaced as a comment on the question will be poor advice; and it is here.

The OpenDKIM people provide [an `opendkim.service` file for systemd](https://sources.debian.net/src/opendkim/2.11.0~alpha-10/contrib/systemd/opendkim.service/).  It is geared towards RedHat and its `/etc/sysconfig` system rather than towards Debian and its `/etc/default` system, and so takes no notice of `/etc/default/opendkim` at all.

Rather than fix it, the Debian people provide [*another* `opendkim.service` file for systemd](https://sources.debian.net/src/opendkim/2.11.0~alpha-10/debian/opendkim.service/) that is used in place of the OpenDKIM-supplied one in Debian packages.  That service unit does not read either `/etc/sysconfig/opendkim` or `/etc/default/opendkim` and hardwires the location of the `AF_LOCAL` socket that OpenDKIM uses.  That is what one gets as `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service`.

One might think that one edits `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service`, therefore.  One does not.  The systemd rule is that one does not edit package-supplied service unit files in `/lib/systemd`.  The systemd way of modifying this service is to add an override INI file in the `/etc/systemd/system/opendkim.service.d/` directory.  This contains a snippet of the part of the package-supplied service unit that one wants to override.

One might think that one simply creates such a snippet, therefore.  One does not.  The Debian people have provided [a "generator" program named `opendkim.service.generate`](https://sources.debian.net/src/opendkim/2.11.0~alpha-10/debian/opendkim.service.generate/) that automatically creates such a snippet from the contents of the `/etc/default/opendkim` file, overriding `User`, `Group`, and `ExecStart` as appropriate.

The problem is that the Debian people have not wired this generator properly into systemd.  It isn't really a *systemd* generator, which has a specific form and has a specific kind of output which this program does not have.  Nor is it hooked into the Debian package installation and removal process.  You need to run `/lib/opendkim/opendkim.service.generate` by hand, followed by an explicit `systemctl daemon-reload`.

## Further reading

- Georges Gouriten (2017-04-25).  *[systemd service overrides opendkim.conf socket at start](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861169)*.  Debian Bug #861169.

Comment: Many thanks. I suppose this might also apply for the opendmarc service - will go check that out. Did not expect that the problem was that the package has something funky going on. In the general case, though, should I still be able to edit /etc/default/[service], and the packaged service unit file or generator is expected to pick up the config parameters? And if it does not, I would then write a snippet?